# Samsung Galaxy S10+ randomly switches to roaming SIM and forces enable data roaming!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-10, google-fit

I have the latest firmware update, and I'm using it with 2 SIMs; Sim #1 is a Google-Fi on roaming, and Sim #2 is the local default sim. I choose SIM 2 to be the default for everything (calls, SMSs, and data). However, I kept seeing the mobile for some reason switches the data to SIM 1, however, I disabled *data roaming*, and surprisingly, the mobile still randomly changes to SIM 1 (Google Fi) and also consume data!!

Comment: in developer options there is setting "aggressive handover" maybe it is related. btw you should switch sim 2 to slot 1 because one some devices only the 1st slot is full featured (at least, for my device)

Comment: I just checked all "Developer options" and there is not "Agrresive handover" or anything similar.

Comment: nevermind. it is not related at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/3au0S.png